# Mongo query find array of years

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have 10,000 documents from various dates going back 100 years.

I want to now find the distinct set of years to make it easier to navigate.  I want to omit any years that do not have documents.

Example:

- 2016: has docs, include
- 2015: no doc, exclude
- 2014: has docs, include
- 2013: has docs, include
- 2012: no docs, exclude

etc.

What's the most efficient way to query the collection of docs in mongo and find the set of years?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/#exp._S_year) operator in a `$group` aggregate for this.

Assuming docs in a `test` collection with a date field named `date`:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {$year: '$date'}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically describing the `$addToSet` functionality which you can read [about in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/).